# Why does domus have masculine forms?

Tags: declension

The word domus is normally a feminine, IVth declension noun and hence the adjectives that modify it are feminine.

However, sometimes domus appears to take masculine forms in some cases. For example, we have the "Comes Domorum" (the count of the houses), who was the official in charge of the imperial palaces. Likewise, the ablative domo and plural accusative domos are also found. What is the explanation for this? Why would domus have these gender-irregular forms?

Answer (score 8):

In Old Latin *domus* (then *domos*) was usually declined as a second-declension noun, though it was feminine even then. It's probably the case that it was **shifted into the fourth declension** in an attempt to make its unusual gender make sense—so it's not the retained second-declension forms that are unusual, it's the new fourth-declension ones.
This actually happened to a greater or lesser extent for a lot of feminine second-declension nouns: e.g. *nurus* 'daughter-in-law' has fully joined the fourth declension (cf. its Greek cognate νυός, still a second-declension feminine), while *fagus* 'beech' and *laurus* 'laurel' are still in the second declension but also have an attested acc. pl. in *-us*. Feminine second-declension nouns seem to have confused Romans nearly as much as they confuse students today. (Conversely, *quercus* 'oak' is a native fourth-declension noun that has an attested gen. pl. *quercorum*.)
For *domus*, this shift was already underway in Old Latin, and pretty much completed in Classical Latin, apart from the occasional now-irregular form and archaism.

As for why *domos* was feminine in the first place, that's less clear. We can reconstruct perhaps three basic Proto-Indo-European words built on the root **dem-* in the o-grade meaning 'house' based on reflexes in daughter languages:

- Athematic root noun **dṓm* < **dóm-s*: Greek δῶ (neuter), Armenian *town* (no gender), Sanskrit *dám* (masculine)
- Thematic (o-stem) **dóm-o-s*: Greek δόμος (masculine), Sanskrit *dáma* (masculine)
- Athematic u-stem **dóm-u-s*: Old Church Slavonic *domŭ* (masculine), Lithuanian *nãmas* (masculine), Vedic Sanskrit *dámūnas-* (a derived adjective, 'of the house'), Armenian *tanow-tēr* (a compound, 'house-lord')

PIE o-stems gave rise to Latin's second declension and u-stems to its fourth, but as *domus*'s membership of the fourth declension seems to be an innovation we can disregard influence from PIE **dómus* (which is certainly masculine anyway). PIE o-stems in **-os* were overwhelmingly masculine, and the Greek and Sankrit seem to confirm **dómos* was too; by rights a Latin *domus* inherited from PIE **dómos* should be masculine.

The gender of PIE athematics is less predictable (much like the Latin third declension, into which most of them went), and it's very inconvenient none of the high-profile reflexes of **dṓm* is feminine. Mainly on the strength of Latin (!), **dṓm* is still usually taken to be feminine, though, and if that's assumed, then Latin *domus* could have retained its feminine gender from it, after it either merged with **dómos* or (in my view more likely) independently became thematised (in which case it effectively hopped declensions from the third to the second to the fourth over the centuries).

Some sources worth your time (though they don't say anything else that's relevant here, I don't think):

- Michael Weiss, *Outline of the Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin*.
- Andrew L. Sihler, *New Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin*.
- Michiel De Vaan, *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages*.

Comment: One quibble: the Armenian cognate is (orthographic) town, (phonological) /tun/. I note that you use the orthographic spelling in tanow-. Otherwise an excellent answer,

Comment: @fdb Yeah, I got *tanow-* from Weiss and *tun* from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%BF%D5%B8%D6%82%D5%B6#Old_Armenian), where it's positioned as if it's a transliteration, but I see it can't actually correspond to the word in the Armenian alphabet. Armenian isn't my area, obviously.

Answer (score 6):

Although *domus* may look masculine, it's a feminine noun through and through — that is, there are no masculine forms, as you say.

According to *[Latin Grammar](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/4th-declension-stem-paradigm-and-gender)* by Allen and Greenough:

> **90.** Most nouns of the 4th Declension in -us are masculine.
>
> Exceptions:
>
> The following are feminine:
>
> **acus**, **anus**, **colus**, **domus**, **īdūs** (plural), **manus**, **nurus**, **porticus**,
> **quīnquātrūs** (plural), **socrus**, **tribus**
>
> with a few names of plants and trees. Also, rarely, **penus**, **specus**.

From the *[Latin Grammar](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gender)*:

> Grammatical Gender is a formal distinction as to sex where no actual
> sex exists in the object. **It is shown by the form of the adjective
> joined with the noun**.

In other words, gender is not tied to the declension or how the declension might appear to you, but to the adjectives joined with it.

Therefore, in spite of appearances, *domus* is feminine:

| Case | Singular | Plural |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nominative | domus | domus |
| Genitive | domus/domi | domorum/domuum |
| Dative | domui/domo/domu | domibus |
| Accusative | domum | domus/domos |
| Ablative | domu/domo | domibus |
| Vocative | domus | domus |
| Locative | domi | domibus |

In your example, *Comes Domorum*, there is no adjective involved — just the noun itself *Domorum* which is feminine. The same is true of *domo*, *domos* — all are feminine.

Comment: Uh, domorum is not femine. That is the masculine form. The feminine IVth declension genitive plural is domuum. I know that domus is feminine. I said that IN THE QUESTION ITSELF. There is no need to be telling me that domus is feminine. I KNOW THAT. The question is why does this feminine word have masculine forms.

Comment: @TylerDurden Those forms are not masculine or feminine in themselves. Most words in the second and fourth declensions are masculine, but the forms of those words are not called masculine forms. The term "masculine form" is only used for adjectives, where gender works with far fewer exceptions than in nouns. I fully agree with the answer: Those forms can look masculine by association to a lot of masculine nouns, but they are not masculine forms.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I guess we are getting into semantics here, but I view -arum and -uum as feminine forms of the genitive and -orum as the masculine/neuter form of the plural genitive, and I think the Romans would agree with me. If a Roman overheard somebody talking and heard nothing but -orum, the Roman would assume men (or something masculine) was being discussed.

Comment: @TylerDurden I don't think that's correct. Neuter nouns also populate the second declension, and -orum is just as likely to be neuter plural as masculine plural. There's also a long list of islands and trees that are feminine second declension, the ending of which in genitive plural would be -orum while their modifying adjectives would end in -arum. That said, there is a question here why *domus* has two forms. I think the mix-up here just comes from different terminology used (i.e. to have said 2nd/4th decl. forms instead of m/f).

Comment: @TylerDurden Quin per silvam aliquam ambulas odoribusque suavibus altarum populorum, fagorum, fraxinorum, pinorum, alnorum, ulmorum delectaris? 

Answer (score 6):

We don't exactly know why *domus* has both second and fourth declension forms, but one possibility is that there were originally two separate words that merged, perhaps because a feminine second declension *domus* is unusual. It's also possible that there was only the o-stem and over time Romans used fourth declension endings for it, for the same reason as above.

From De Vaan:

> In PIE, there was a root noun nom.sg. **dōm*, gen. **dem-s*. Probably, a *u*-stem derivative also existed (yielding Slav. **domu-* 'house' and Gk. δμώς 'slave' < **dm-ou-).
> ...
> The f. gender of *domus* probably is due to the original root noun. Old Latin mainly has *o*-stem forms; the change into a *u*-stem which some case forms show may be explained from an attempt to adapt the declension type of *domus* to its f. gender, which is unusual for Latin *o*-stems (apart from tree-names).

Comment: de Vaan does not say that these "were originally two separate words" that "merged". He says that this is one word, which shifted (at least partially) from 2nd to 4th declension.

Comment: @fdb I didn't say De Vaan said that. I said it. But De Vaan notes right there in the quoted text that "a u-stem derivative also existed." It ultimately doesn't matter whether the u-stem existed in Latin or was just created as a part of regularization, as either way we originally have an o-stem noun that shifted into a u-stem noun, and the most likely reason is that feminine 2nd declension nouns are a rarity. But you're right De Vaan doesn't actually say the u-stem derivative is also found in Latin or that they merged.

Comment: I'm confused by the reference to δμώς. Isn't it from a different PIE root, demh-, cognate with "tame?"

Comment: @BenCrowell It's the [same root](https://www.etymonline.com/word/domestic).

Answer (score 6):

Genitive plural *domōrum*, ablative singular *domō*, and accusative plural *domōs* aren't masculine forms, they're **second-declension forms**.

It's true that *most* first-declension nouns are feminine and *most* second-declension nouns are masculine or neuter, but this is just a rule of thumb. Declension isn't necessarily linked to gender: *nauta* "sailor" is masculine, and *quercus* "oak" is feminine, for example. So a good sailor is a *nauta bon**us***, and a good oak is a *quercus bon**a***, and good houses in the genitive plural are *domōrum bon**ārum***.